# How to do a specific auto refresh in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I have 3 files, model.ts, modal.html and modal.ts. I would like to do the auto refresh only when the modal is open and stop it when it is closed. my modal shows me information continuously.

modal.htlm :

```
<button class="btn btn-success" style="padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem; float: left; font-size: 12px;"(click)="viewFile(model)">Voir</button>
<div class="modal" id="mdl"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" 
    [ngStyle]="{'display': mdlIsOpen ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': 1}">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Hello</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="openContent(false)">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style="white-space: pre-wrap" innerHTML="{{reponse}}"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" align="right">
                <button type="button" id="btnOK" class="btn btn-success"
                    (click)="openContent(false)">close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

modal.ts:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  private updateSubscription: Subscription;
  reponse: String;
  model: Model[];
  constructor(private modelService: ModelService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  refreshAuto(){
    console.log(this.mdlIsOpen); 
    if(this.mdlIsOpen === true){
        this.updateSubscription = interval(10000).subscribe(
            (val) => { 
                this.refresh();
                this.refreshAuto();
            });  
        }
       }
refreshFile(): void {
    this.viewFile(this.model);
}

refresh(): void {
    this.view(this.model);
}

openContent(open: boolean): void {
    console.log(open);
    this.mdlIsOpen = open;
}

viewFile(model: Model): void {
    this.modelService.viewFile(model)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.openContent(true);
            this.reponse = res;
            //console.log(res);
            
            this.refreshAuto();
            //clearInterval(this.interval);   
        }, err => {
            console.log("here for view");
            console.log(err);
            alert (JSON.parse(err.error).message);
        }
        );
}

view(model: Model): void {
    this.modelService.viewFile(model)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.reponse = res;
            //console.log(res);
        }, err => {
            console.log("here for view");
            console.log(err);
            alert (JSON.parse(err.error).message);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

model.ts:

```
export class Model {
 Id: number;
 mode: number;
 App: string;
 name: string;
}
```

but its not working well, when I close the modal and mdlIsOpen goes to false, the auto refresh continues.

Comment: Consider using takeUntil on the interval(). It might solve your problem

Comment: Can you show me an example with my code please?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Do not continually call this method

```
 refreshAuto(){
    console.log(this.mdlIsOpen); 
    if(this.mdlIsOpen === true){
        this.updateSubscription = interval(10000).subscribe(
            (val) => { 
                this.refresh();
                this.refreshAuto();
            });  
        }
       }
```

Why? Because interval never stops on it's own. Each time this is called it sets up another interval observable.

Step 2) *"I would like to do the auto refresh only when the modal is open"* This code is ambiguous

```
openContent(open: boolean): void {
    console.log(open);
    this.mdlIsOpen = open;
}
```

We can't tell from the code who would ever want to openConent and set the open value to false. OpenContent should probably always be to open the dialog.

Step 3) Determine when to change this.mdlIsOpen to false. One good place, for sure is in ngOnDestroy. You may also stop the interval timer there too.

Step 4) Provide a method isOpen(open:boolean) which allows an explicit self explaining entry into your component to open or close the dialog.

Step 5) MatDialog does have a [close option](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)

**Example**

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material/dialog";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor( private dialog: MatDialog) {}
 // The HTML button click handler
 onButtonClicked($event) {
    let httpClient: HttpClient = new HttpClient(this.httpHandler);
// Causes a CORS error 
httpClient.get("http://www.google.com").subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        let dc = new MatDialogConfig();
        dc.autoFocus = true;
        // Important part
        dc.data = error;
        this.dialog.open(ErrorHandlerComponent, dc);
      }
    );
  }
```

And ErrorHandlerComponent

```
export class ErrorHandlerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  error: HttpErrorResponse;
  constructor(
    // Must inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) 
    public data: any,
    private ref: ElementRef,
    private HtmlElementService: HtmlElementService
  ) {
    // Html binds to this.error
    this.error = data;
  }
```

The Injected Component's HTML

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ error.statusText }}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Message</p>
  {{ error.message }}
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button class="mat-raised-button" mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
  <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" (click)="save()">Copy</button>
</div>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your modal close method unsubscribe the interval observable.

```
openContent(open: boolean): void {
    console.log(open);
    this.mdlIsOpen = open;
    this.updateSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```